# How do I write a plugin that replaces any function execution with a string result

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I have a plugin:

```
var Foo = function() {};

function lookup(key) {
    // pretend this lookup function returns a different value based on key input
    return 'something else';
}

Foo.prototype.apply = function() {
    compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation, params) {
        compilation.dependencyFactories.set(ConstDependency, new NullFactory());
        compilation.dependencyTemplates.set(ConstDependency, new ConstDependency.Template());
    });

    compiler.parser.plugin('call abc.bar', function(expr) {
        var param = this.evaluateExpression(expr.arguments[0]);
        var result = lookup(param.string);
        var dep = new ConstDependency(JSON.stringify(result), expr.range);
        dep.loc = expr.loc;
        this.state.current.addDependency(dep);
        return true;
    });
};
```

--> When I run it against this file:

```
var someString = abc.bar('something');
```

--> It gets compiled and replaced with:

```
var someString = 'something else';
```

--> But when I do this:

```
var abc = require('abc');
var someString = abc.bar('something');
```

--> It gets compiled to:

```
var abc = webpack_require(123);
var someString = abc.bar('something');
```

What's happening and why does the compiler behave differently when you have a local variable?

And how do I make it so the replacement still happens?

I have also seen function calls being ignored if they are inside an object declaration:

```
var someObj = { someKey: abc.bar('something'); }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to get this working?

Comment: I never got this working.  I gave up on it.  I opened an issue with webpack.  They closed it "due to inactivity" : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2585